# Application stays open due to processes

Tags: c#

I'm rather new to C# so I'm not sure if this is even possible...

What I'm trying to do is use an application form to launch other programs via `Process`, such as Notepad, and then close my original application while Notepad is still running.

```cs
Process notePad = new Process();
notePad.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
notePad.Start();
Application.Exit();
```

From what I've found, I have to close/kill the Notepad process  in order to close the launching application. I'd like Notepad to remain open, however.

Is there any way to achieve this via C#?

Comment: It is because the process is started as a child process of your application. You can't kill the parent process without the child process getting killed, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this?

```
using(Process notePad = Process.Start("notepad.exe","")) { }
Application.Exit();
```

Comment: This launches Notepad, but my application still seems to be ignoring the `Application.Exit();`
.
Edit:
I done some more testing and tried `Environment.Exit(0);` and it works perfectly, thank you :)
(I'm now wondering why it wouldn't accept `Application.Exit();`, though)

Comment: You don't need to call Application.Exit(), the process will go out of scope and be cleaned up after you leave the "using" scope.

Answer (score 1):

if you want notepad still open after close the form use this code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread notepad_opener = new Thread(opener);
    notepad_opener.Start();
}
public void opener()
{
    Process.Start("notepad.exe");
    Application.Exit();
}
```

i try this and notepad still open :D

Comment: Cheers mate :)
I was hoping to do it without a button. But I've found my issue to be the use of `Application.Exit();`, rather than `Environment.Exit(0);`

Comment: you can put it any method :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `UseShellExecute` property to True; see [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the Id of Process you have started:

```
int id = notePad.Id;
```

Then Kill it when you want:

```
Process.GetProcessById(id).Kill();
```